# Macbook cannot connect to Dell external display with USB-C

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb

Any mac device I own (Macbook Air 2020, Macbook Air M1, Macbook Air M2) does not connect to the Dell external display I own (u2723qe). Under the display settings, the monitors cannot be detected. The monitor was fully functional without problem for about half a year until the problem appeared.

The display is proven functional, as it can power a PC through the DP port or connect to my laptop through HDMI + conversion.

The Thunderbolt ports are proven functional, as the display still charges the laptops, but they simply will not transfer data.

The cable is proven functional, as I was sucessfully able to connect my display to another monitor from another brand without issue.

My own hypothesis to the issue is that it is related to the 90w fast charging capabilities, due to the fact that HDMI / monitors that don't charge are functional.

I have tried the popular method of "unplugging the monitor power", which unfortunately did not work.

Any help, similar experiences or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it just macOS that doesn't work on the USB-C port, or Windows/Linux devices don't work when you use the USB-C port? Also, can you provide a photo of which USB-C port you're plugging into? Your monitor has both an upstream and a downstream USB-C port, and only one of those will work as an input. Also, what's the exact model of the cable you're using? Not all cables are created equal, and while I'd expect most to work at 2160p @ 60 Hz, it may be misbehaving.

Comment: Is USB-C your only choice? Have you tried using a HDMI? I have 1x LG 38" which I connects to a MacBook Pro, and now Mac mini, via USB-C. I also have 2 unit of Dell U2412M which I connect via HDMI (direct to the MacBook Pro/Mac mini) and another one via a HDMI dongle from Apple, which connects to USB-C on the Mac. All 3 displays are working concurrently. So I wonder if it was the USB-C and suggest you try with the HDMI first.

Comment: @ringgitmalaysia
Yes, using HDMI works. However, I can also confirm that the cable works, as it was able to connect to another 4k monitor from another brand. It simply would not transfer data through the dell monitor. thank you for your help.

Comment: @JMY1000 I do not have a windows device. However, this monitor is new and hence likely not the monitor's problem. I have tried multiple ports, and am aware that some of the USBC ports are downstream. I believe that there are 2 upstream USBC ports for my model– one that supports 90w fast charging and one that does not. I have tried both with all my cabels. 

I also have various cabels, 2 from dell (which both do not work) and one that I have bought on a 3rd party with data transfer capablities, as it sucessfully connected my laptop to a 4k monitor created by another brand. 

ty 4 ur help

Comment: You could try using Bootcamp on the 2020 MacBook Air to see if it's a macOS specific problem, but given that the display was functional for a year without issues and it's only cropped up now, I would probably just RMA the display to Dell. It sounds like there was some sort of hardware fault with the USB-C port.